# Ive made a welcome command so when a user enters the server it welcomes it or if they leave it says goodbye, but theres a prob i dont know how to fix

Tags: discord.py

This is discord py by the way, so what the prob is that my bot is in multiple servers, so if i set the channel to something in another server, all the servers which the bot is in, if members join or leave, the message comes only in that 1 server which has it set, so how can i make it that its seperate for all servers
btw heres my code:

````
@cfire.command(aliases=['logs'])
@commands.guild_only()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def member_logs(ctx, channel:discord.TextChannel):
    global ch
    ch = channel.id
    await ctx.send(f"Set {channel} to the member logs!")

@member_logs.error
async def l_er(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send('Please provide a valid channel')
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send('You do not have permission to use that command!')

@cfire.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    global ch
    if ch != None:
        oil = discord.Embed(title=f'Hey {member} welcome to our server!', description='Hope you have a great time!', colour = discord.Color.purple())
        oil.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
        oil.add_field(name='Account created on:', value=member.created_at.strftime("%a, %d, %B, %Y, %I:%M, %p UTC"), inline=False)
        oil.add_field(name='Joined server on:', value=member.joined_at.strftime("%a, %d, %B, %Y, %I:%M, %p UTC"), inline=False)
        await cfire.get_channel(ch).send(embed=oil)
    else:
        pass

@cfire.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    global ch
    if ch != None:
        aoil = discord.Embed(title=f'Sad to see you leave {member}', description='Hope you had a great time!', colour = discord.Color.purple())
        aoil.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
        aoil.add_field(name='Account created on:', value=member.created_at.strftime("%a, %d, %B, %Y, %I:%M, %p UTC"), inline=False)
        aoil.add_field(name='Joined server on:', value=member.joined_at.strftime("%a, %d, %B, %Y, %I:%M, %p UTC"), inline=False)
        await cfire.get_channel(ch).send(embed=aoil)
    else:
        pass```
cfire is my bot var
````

Comment: You have to create a database or JSON file and re-structure your code so that every guild is saved in it + the channel. Your command has to be re-coded too, I guess.

Comment: oh ok but how should i do that?

Comment: Try to read the docs. Make an honest attempt and share your code, approaches and the errors you face. I would recommend a JSON file.